# Literature on thematic 4D maps

Tags: mapping, gis, cartography, literature-request

I need to understand more about thematic 4D mapping. I would roughly classify it as a method of cartography. In particular I want to do research on what software is being used to create thematic 4D maps or other 4D maps (like 4D maps in city planning). Also I want to find out what some general aspects of thematic 4D maps are.

Since this is kind of a special field, I'll probably have to look in more specialized literature database, other then Google Scholar and the like. The number of results I get on the broader literature databases are very limited.

What literature databases come to your mind where I might find anything about this topic?

To get an idea what thematic 4D mapping is all about, here is probably the most recognized paper on the subject: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1179/1743277413Y.0000000062

Comment: Not sure, but would others agree that 4D mapping might fall more towards GIS SE?  I guess it's in that blurry area between cartography and GIS, but seems to be more about the computational data work rather than physical geography mapping itself?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about maybe putting my question there. But since this method is being used in so many different areas recently, like urban planning or oceanography, I though I might just as well ask here. Also some researchers use software that is untypical for GIS, like the Unity game development engine and they don't really meet the requirements to be called a GIS tool.